# scope function inside function python3?

Tags: python, scope

while i was reading about namespacing and scopping in python, i read that

```
-the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
-the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
-the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
-the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names
```

but when i tried this :

```
def test() :
    name = 'karim'

    def tata() :
        print(name)
        name='zaka'
        print(name)
    tata()
```

i have received this error :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

when the statement **print(name)** the tata() function will not find name in the current scope so python will go up in scope and find it in test() function scope no??

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can use `nonlocal name` to tell python that `name` is not defined in the local scope and it should look for it in an outer scope.

This works:

```
def tata():
    nonlocal name
    print(name)
    name='zaka'
    print(name)
```